# C# - Open an app as second process in the Task Manager

Tags: c#, process, taskmanager

I want to open an different app and to appears like it's an process of the app itself and don't appear as a different one in the task manager processes list.

Something like:

[image]

Can Process.Start() do it?

**Solved!
Well it seems that always when an app starts a process, the main app it'll be its parent. I didn't knew that :)**

Comment: CreateProcess should do it provided that you own the parent process.  I'm not sure I'm comfortable telling how to do it for processes you don't own though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Process.Start` with a `ProcessStartInfo` and ensuring `UseShellExecute` is `false` should probably do it. However, the process being launched may do something that breaks this behavior. It could, for example, just be a stub launcher that starts another process then quits.